# MatOfKeypoint returns floating point coordinates in openCV 2.4.11

Tags: java, c++, opencv, sift

im trying to use the SIFT detector but when i check the points i receive i noticed that some has floating points, for example x=11.96349811553955 and y=328.89013671875 which is really weird, cause coordinates should be integers.
according to the documentation, MatOfKeypoint consists of KeyPoint objects which holds 6 attributes, point, angle, class_id, octave, response and diameter.

is this correct? if not how can i get the correct coordinates?
im using this line of code keypoints.toList().get(0).pt.x and keypoints.get(point, 0)[1] both works but returns floating point.

i tried in openCV 3.0 same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the KeyPoint.pt object **is** a Point2f float point. also, angle, response and size are float, too. just read the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/features2d/KeyPoint.html)

Comment: Thanks Berak, yes im aware of that, but it doesn't make sense for a the coordinate to have anything other than 0 after the floating point right? coordinates are distinctive integer values, it's either 11 or 12 not 11.9

Comment: "coordinates are distinctive integer values" - no, not nessecarily. there's a lot of sense in subpixel accuracy for operations like this. space is continuous, only pixels are discrete

Comment: could you elaborate more on that? what i understand is that, i should receive a point, this point has an orientation, octave for the scale and the area size. so why would i need the subpixel when i have the scale space?